# Is it possible to convert table data to similar type using VALUE operator

Tags: type-conversion, abap

I think this question is best illustrated with an example. I've got 2 tables of different data types (but `table_type1` is easily convertable to `table_type2`)

> `i_tab1 type table_type1` (fields: `matnr`,`maktx`,`spras`)
>   `i_tab2 type table_type2` (fields: `mandt`,`matnr`)

Is it possible to use the `VALUE` operator, possibly with `FOR line in i_tab1` (or maybe a similar inline commands) to convert and transfer data of i_tab1 to i_tab2 ? I was thinking of something like the following:

```
i_tab2 = VALUE # (for line in i_tab1 
                        BASE = gt_itab2 (
                           MANDT = sy-mandt;
                           MATNR = line-matnr
                        )
                  ).
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were close. Here is a solution you might find helpful.

```
REPORT ZZZ.

TYPES: BEGIN OF tab1_line,
    matnr TYPE mara-matnr,
    maktx TYPE makt-maktx,
    spras TYPE makt-spras,
  END OF tab1_line,
  BEGIN OF tab2_line,
    mandt TYPE t000-mandt,
    matnr TYPE mara-matnr,
  END OF tab2_line,
  table_type1 TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF tab1_line WITH EMPTY KEY,
  table_type2 TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF tab2_line WITH EMPTY KEY.

DATA:
g_tab1 TYPE table_type1,
g_tab2 TYPE table_type2.

START-OF-SELECTION.
g_tab2 = VALUE #( BASE g_tab2 FOR i IN g_tab1 ( mandt = sy-mandt matnr = i-matnr ) ).
```

Comment: Thank you! I was reading the official documentation and couldn't figure out why `BASE = xxxx` didn't work, when I copied the exact example they gave (turns out I didn't need the equals sign). After poking around in your solution I realized that the return structure of `VALUE` was same as `g_tab2` (destination) by default (and I misunderstood the purpose of `BASE` addition, which was to assign initial values to `line` or `i` in your example, and not to determine initial structure). In other words base is not even necessary in this case. Still it's nice to know how to use it... :D